# Is the computer security scenario in the movie "Die Hard 4" realistic?

Tags: hard-sci-fi, computers

I watched the movie Die Hard 4, in which they show how someone hacked the complete system of US. They were able to get inside every traffic camera and even cameras in lifts.

I want to know if this sort of system exists in reality where police can have control of every camera from one location, what sort of computers and programming system they use for that, and how everything is interlinked?

Comment: As real as Tron

Comment: This probably belongs on Skeptics SE (they had an equivalent Q about traffic lights hacking)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about SFF. Die Hard is not "hard sci-fi" either.

Answer (score 15):

In a word, no.

For one thing, a lot of cameras are closed-circuit, so they're only available at the local security office or where ever else they might happen to have their monitors.

Even if they're not closed circuit, I doubt the majority of cameras are exposed to the internet.

And of those that are exposed to the internet, there is no single 'system' that controls them all. While it may be possible (indeed, potentially rather easy) to hack any individual camera on the internet, taking control of every camera exposed on the internet would be completely infeasible in terms of time, never mind identifying them all.

Comment: And every system likely uses a different location notation to try and isolate it to the ones you want so quickly would be impossible.

Comment: In fact, the answer to almost every question that boils down to "I saw this done with computers in a movie; is that really how it works?" is "No."

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis: With the one notable exception being all the hacking and phone phreaking in WarGames. (not including anything to do with Joshua)

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis: Another notable exception is The Social Network, which gets pretty much all of the technology right.

Comment: @Mike Maybe it gets the technology right, but you can't really say hackathons are usually done in a party with semi-naked hookers and heavy drinking. As real as the "speed hacking" in Swordfish ;)

Answer (score -2):

This is very possible and it is how groups like Anonymous get into systems.

Disclaimer: I do not know how the traffic light cameras or hotel cameras operate internally but I could take a guess.

If the cameras are Closed Circuit they are still being monitored from a location. Typically you'll have Network Operation Centers. These centers have access to all of the video feeds. These video feeds are not on the internet. But SOME computers in this network are on the Internet, thus this is what happens.

Hacker -- |Internet| --> Compromised Machine ----> Closed Circuit Machine --> Camera

In order for this to work we'd have to make some assumptions:

1. The 'hacker' is sufficiently skilled
2. There is at least one machine that is accessible from the internet that sits inside the Government facility
3. That machine that is accessible has at least some access to another machine that can be compromised to eventually get to the camera feed.

Based on how I have seen networks setup and some of the problems that LinkedIn, Playstation, etc. have I think it is completely feasible.

The bogus parts of these movies are the password 'crackers'. That is completely bogus. You don't solve random digits of someone's password / code like they show in the movies. Most hackers won't brute force passwords. They will use [Social Enginering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) or a vulnerability in the system.

Comment: Care to comment?

Comment: It wasn't me, but "closed circuit" by definition cannot be accessed from any outside system - they're not hooked up to systems unrelated to their task.  There is no possible way to use the internet to get into a closed-circuit security system.

Comment: @Izkata You have to understand there are two worlds. The Idealistic world and the Pragmatic world. We are assuming that all implementors of said system did everything perfectly and correctly. Not only that but Closed Circuit does not mean it cannot be accessed. It means it has a limited number of access points and does not broadcast. All that needs to happen is a chain of networks to be connected through ignorance to allow eventual access.